# Cannot install psget

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install [psget](http://psget.net/) on windows 10 from powershell in admin mode but I get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
Downloading PsGet from https://github.com/psget/psget/raw/master/PsGet/PsGet.psm1
Invoke-WebRequest : The given path's format is not supported.
At line:42 char:13
+             Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -OutFile $SaveToLocation
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletIEDomNotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Import-Module : The specified module 'C:\Users\myuser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules C:\Users\myuser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PsGet' was not loaded
because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:105 char:9
+         Import-Module -Name $Destination\PsGet
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Users\myuser\Do...l\Modules\PsGet:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

PsGet is installed and ready to use
USAGE:
    PS> import-module PsGet
    PS> install-module PsUrl

For more details:
    get-help install-module
Or visit http://psget.net
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

As suggested below PsGet is actually already installed on windows 10. I have then continued with the next step:

[image]

and as can be seen it installs successfully (needs to be done running as administrator). After a restart of the powershell console I still don't get any color highlighting though:

[image]

Any ideas?

Btw: the folder **C:\Users[my-user]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules** is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um... psget as in PowerShellGet module that I am almost certain comes on Win 10. I believe your error is even telling you that. Where it says PsGet is installed and ready to use.

Comment: I struggled with this too. I think that psget is now deprecated in favour of built in stuff from powershell 5 onwards. You can see the gallery here https://www.powershellgallery.com/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the script at `http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1` tries to decide where to install by querying for `@($env:PSModulePath -split ';')` and then limit the search for paths under `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

It appears that in your computer, PSModulePath includes twice the folder `C:\Users\myuser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`, which causes an issue with the installation script.

You can do either one of these two options to solve it:

1. Remove one instance of `C:\Users\myuser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` [from the PSModulePath variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878326(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. Install `PsGet` manually using the instructions [in the official website](http://psget.net/).